# I installed KDE desktop on Xubuntu and installed some stuff but some applications including Firefox and Chrome show a weird font

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, kde, fonts

I installed KDE-desktop and the thing that replaces light dm and also some other things a friend suggested me like dolphin for viewing files etc.

however i get the following problem with the browsers. they aren't showing the proper font style. It wasn't this font while i was using them in xfce.

could anyone please help me figure out how to fix this weird font bug.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is probably to do a new install of Kubuntu.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I kinda use this laptop for university stuff so can't really experimet too much right now.

Comment: Sounds as if you already have started to experiment. Anyway, hopefully someone is able to give you a hand.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yeah true, but i thought the process of switching wouldn't be so painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one responded I figured it own on my own.

Reason is that most of the applications were made for xfce since that was my old desktop and it uses gtk2/gtk3 for application styling.

so in the settings i had to modify the Application style for gtk2/gtk3 applications and just set the font there to the desired normal `Noto Sans` font.